# Button not clickable in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I've got screen layout as shown in the screenshot below.
All looks good on screen but the button just won't react to any user input - i.e. connected @IBAction doesn't get triggered.
I believe that a specific constraint is causing the issue but I can't figure out why and they all look healthy to me. 
Can anyone spot it or make out what the problem is?
Thanks for your help in advance!

[image]

Comment: Apply Stack can have frame .zero, which is not visible with eyes. The button is still there, but its container has .zero frame.
You can test by setting `clipToBounds = true` for your stack view. If button disappears it means I am right :)

Comment: Unclickable view usually means the view is outside the bounds of its superview. Use the View Debugger to confirm this. It looks to me like the stack view has insufficient constraints. I am surprised you are not getting a warning in Xcode (at the top of the view list on the left, cut out of your screen shot); are you? If so, you need to fix that before running.

Comment: @ShalvaAvanashvili: I've just tried to set `clipToBounds = true" for the Apply-Stack and then also for the ApplyButton itself. Button remains visible and still doesn't react to user input. Not sure what you mean with "Apply Stack can have frame .zero" What would I need to change?

Comment: @BernhardEngl When you tap the button, does it visibly react? A tapped button usually fades or somehow responds to the highlighting of being touched; is it doing that? If not, it is probably _outside_ one of its superviews. This could be ApplyStack or Date Container View. Or else some other view we don't know about is in front of it. As I told you, you can diagnose this instantly in the View Debugger, so just do that. If it _does_ respond, the problem is in your code that configures or responds to the button's action.

Comment: @matt: You're right. I did get a "height ambiguity" warning for the surrounding Date Container View. Fixed that. Works now! Thanks!! ;-)

Comment: OK, please delete the question as this is a trivial solution: all you had to do was pay attention to what Xcode was telling you. :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @matt, I had a missing height constraint for the surrounding Container View. Once I added that the button did respond to user input again. Cheers @matt!!